# How to get the month label on ASP.Net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, charts

I have created an ASP.Net chart control which is receiving date from database and I have the following code to show it on the chart e.g. (Monday, 01-12-2015)

```
<LabelStyle Format="dddd, dd-MM-yy" Angle="-90" IsEndLabelVisible="false" />
```

I am wondering how can I change it to show only month. e.g (December)? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Format" parameter define how the date will be displayed. To show only month name, it will be "MMMM":

```
<LabelStyle Format="MMMM" Angle="-90" IsEndLabelVisible="false" />
```

Comment: small case mmmm didnt work for me but capital case MMMM did the trick. Please change m to capitals and I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: BTW do you know how can I add year with it?

Comment: "MMMM yyyy" will display "December 2015"

Answer (score 1):

You can use "MMMM" format.

Here is the reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx